# Creating a extended user profile

Tags: django, django-registration

I have an extended UserProfile model in django:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
  #other things in that profile
```

And a signals.py:

```
from registration.signals import user_registered
from models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def createUserProfile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  profile = users.models.UserProfile()
  profile.setUser(sender)
  profile.save()

user_registered.connect(createUserProfile, sender=User)
```

I make sure the signal gets registered by having this in my `__init__.py`:

```
import signals
```

So that should create me a new UserProfile for every user that registers, right? But it doesn't. I always get "UserProfile matching query does not exist" errors when I try to log in, which means that the database entry isn't there.

I should say that I use django-registration, which provides the user_registered signal.

The structure of the important apps for this is, that I have one application called "users", there I have: models.py, signals.py, urls.py and views.py (and some other things which shouldn't matter here). The UserProfile class is defined in models.py.

**Update**: I changed the signals.py to:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def create_profile(sender, **kw):
    user = kw["instance"]
    if kw["created"]:
        profile = UserProfile()
        profile.user = user
        profile.save()

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

But now I get a "IntegrityError":

> "column user_id is not unique"

**Edit 2:**

I found it. Looks like somehow I registred the signal twice. The workaround for this is described here: http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Signals#Helppost_saveseemstobeemittedtwiceforeachsave

I had to add a dispatch_uid, now my signals.py looks like this and is working:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from models import UserProfile
from django.db import models

def create_profile(sender, **kw):
    user = kw["instance"]
    if kw["created"]:
        profile = UserProfile(user=user)
        profile.save()

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User, dispatch_uid="users-profilecreation-signal")
```

Comment: Could you post the structure your django app. I am curious about a couple of lines in your code like `profile=user.models.UserProfile()` - do you have a module named 'user'? Where is UserProfile() located.

Comment: it is users, I don't know how that typo got in there, but the problem is the same. I wonder why python did not throw an error for the misspelled path.

Comment: thanks for this solution, im new with django, and i dont khow how ill save others data about the user profile.

i see that your just save the user in the model UserProfile, but how ill save other's data (using your signals.py) from the register form?

Thansk (sorry with the english)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can implement it using post_save on the user:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs["instance"]
    if kwargs["created"]:
        profile = users.models.UserProfile()
        profile.setUser(sender)
        profile.save()

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

**Edit:**
Another possible solution, which is tested and works (I'm using it on my site):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs["instance"]
    if kwargs["created"]:
        up = UserProfile(user=user, stuff=1, thing=2)
        up.save()
post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

Comment: has to be "profile.setUser(user)", i think. But then i get "column user_id is not unique". Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I added another possible solution to my answer, check it out.

Comment: I get "column user_id is not unique", can you please show me your UserProfile model? Maybe I got something with the ForeignKey() wrong.

Comment: Got it to work. Look in my initial post, if you are interested in the solution.

Comment: @Agos It would be very helpful to describe how one gets the values for `stuff` and `thing` in `create_profile`.

Comment: I simply make all the fields on my profile model `default=''` and `blank=True`, so with that, you wouldn't need to pass in any arguments or the stuff=1 and thing=2 @veddermatic

Answer (score 6):

You can get the extended profile to be created when first accessed for each user instead:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    additional_info_field = models.CharField(max_length=50)

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

then use

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
user.profile.additional_info_field
```

ref: http://www.codekoala.com/blog/2009/quick-django-tip-user-profiles/

Answer (score 6):

This helped me: primary_key=True

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, primary_key=True, related_name="user")
    phone = models.CharField(('phone'),max_length=30, blank=False, null=True)
    user_building = models.ManyToManyField(Building, blank=True)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name="added")
```

Comment: primary_key=True implies null=False and unique=True.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/

Answer (score 5):

When you call `profile.setUser()`, I think you want to pass `instance` rather than `sender` as the parameter.

From the [documentation of the user_registered signal](http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/signals.html#registration.signals.user_registered), `sender` refers to the `User` class; `instance` is the actual user object that was registered.

Answer (score 1):

According to my latest research, creating a separate file, e.g., singals.py, does not work.

You'd better connect 'create_profile' to 'post_save' in your models.py directly, otherwise this piece of code won't be executed since it's in a separate file and no one imports it.

My final code for your reference:

```
# models.py

# Here goes the definition of class UserProfile.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...

# Use signal to automatically create user profile on user creation.

# Another implementation:
# def create_user_profile(sender, **kwargs):
#     user = kwargs["instance"]
#     if kwargs["created"]:
#         ...
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """
    :param sender: Class User.
    :param instance: The user instance.
    """
    if created:
        # Seems the following also works:
        #   UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        # TODO: Which is correct or better?
        profile = UserProfile(user=instance)
        profile.save()

post_save.connect(create_user_profile,
                  sender=User,
                  dispatch_uid="users-profilecreation-signal")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update for 2018:**

This question has collected a lot of views, maybe it is time for an update.

This is the latest version for latest Django.

```py
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.conf import settings
from models import UserProfile

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: I think (for 2018, django >=1.11) it should always be: `sender=get_user_model()`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model

Comment: Should `UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)` instead be `UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance, **kwargs)`?

Comment: @theeastcoastwest nope. The `**kwargs` relate to the signal itself, it doesn't contain any data that you would want to use when creating the profile. In fact, you just want to create a clean UserProfile model, not changing it in any way.

Comment: Is there a source where I can read about using signals to create related objects (such as `UserProfile` in this case) vs using Model Managers? Pros and Cons of their approach and best practice kinda recommendation? Thank you.