# How would i use signals to create a new "UserProfile" object when a "User" object is created in django?

Tags: django, signals, profile

Hay, I'm using django's contrib.auth system which obviously allows me to create User objects, I'm also using the profile module. This is loaded through AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE.

Using signals how would i got about create a new UserProfile object when a User is created?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910359/creating-a-extended-user-profile

Comment: I agree, didn't see that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm creating a new entry in Account which acts as my UserProfile:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


from wizard.models import Account

 def make_account(sender, **kwargs):

    if 'created' not in kwargs or not kwargs['created']:
        return

    user = kwargs["instance"]
    account = Account(user=user, name="Account for %s" % user.username)

    account.save()

 post_save.connect(make_account, sender=User, weak=False)
```