# Creating a profile model with both an InlineAdmin and a post_save signal in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-signals

I created a 'profile' model (with a 1-to-1 relationship to the User model) as described on [Extending the existing user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model). The profile model has an optional many-to-one relationship to another model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

As documented there, I also created an inline admin:

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'profiles'
# UserAdmin and unregister()/register() calls omitted, they are straight copies from the Django docs
```

Now if I don't select an `account` in the admin when creating the user, the profile model won't be created. So I [connect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions) to the [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) signal, again just following the documentation:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile_for_new_user(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = Profile(user=instance)
        profile.save()
```

This works fine as long as I do *not* select an `account` in the admin, but if I do, I'll get an `IntegrityError` exception, telling me that `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "app_profile_user_id_key" DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(15) already exists.`

Apparently, the inline admin tries to creates the `profile` instance itself, but my `post_save` signal handler has already created it at that time.

How do I fix this problem, while keeping all of the following requirements?

1. No matter how the new user is created, there will always be a `profile` model linking to it as well afterwards.
2. If the user selects an `account` in the admin during user creation, this `account` will be set on the new `profile` model afterwards. If not, the field is `null.`

Environment: Django 1.5, Python 2.7

Related questions:

- [Creating a extended user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910359/creating-a-extended-user-profile) (similar symptoms, but the cause turned out to be a different one)

Comment: I'm also wondering if it would be better to use `Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)` to create the profile model?

Comment: I've run into the same issue. We're using get_or_create, which doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem can be avoided by setting `primary_key=True` on the `OneToOneField` pointing at the `User` model, as you have figured out yourself.

The reason that this works seems to be rather simple.

When you try to create a model instance and set the `pk` manually before saving it, Django will try to find a record in the database with that `pk` and update it rather than blindly attempting to create a new one. If none exists, it creates the new record as expected.

When you set the `OneToOneField` as the primary key and Django Admin sets that field to the related `User` model's ID, that means the `pk` is already set and Django will attempt to find an existing record first.

This is what happens with the `OneToOneField` set as primary key:

1. Django Admin creates the new `User` instance, with no `id`.
2. Django Admin saves the `User` instance.

   1. Because the `pk` (in this case `id`) is not set, Django attempts to create a new record.
   2. The new record's `id` is set automatically by the database.
   3. The `post_save` hook creates a new `Profile` instance for that `User` instance.
3. Django Admin creates the new `Profile` instance, with its `user` set to the user's `id`.
4. Django Admin saves the `Profile` instance.

   1. Because the `pk` (in this case `user`) is already set, Django attempts to fetch an existing record with that `pk`.
   2. Django finds the existing record and updates it.

If you don't set the primary key explicitly, Django instead adds a field that uses the database's `auto_increment` functionality: the database sets the `pk` to the next largest value that doesn't exist. This means the field will actually be left blank unless you set it manually and Django will therefore always attempt to insert a new record, resulting in a conflict with the uniqueness-constraint on the `OneToOneField`.

This is what causes the original problem:

1. Django Admin creates the new `User` instance, with no `id`.
2. Django Admin saves the `User` instance, the `post_save` hook creating a new `Profile` instance as before.
3. Django Admin creates the new `Profile` instance, with no `id` (the automatically added `pk` field).
4. Django Admin saves the `Profile` instance.

   1. Because the `pk` (in this case `id`) is not set, Django attempts to create a new record.
   2. The database reports a violation of the table's uniqueness-constraint on the `user` field.
   3. Django throws an Exception. You will not go to space today.

Comment: Hm, how to now make a migration from a model where I didn't have `primary_key=True` and now that I do have?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like setting `primary_key=True` on the `OneToOneField` connecting the profile model to the `User` model fixes this issue. However, I don't think I understand all the implications of that and why it helps.

I'll leave this here as a hint, but if that's the best solution and someone could come up with a well-written explanation, I'd upvote/accept that and possibly delete mine.