# Django: Testing if a UserProfile exists before referencing it

Tags: python, django

Trying to do a view in Django, have UserProfile hooked in to be my user profile module. I want to do something like:

```
@login_required
def viewfunction (request):
   if request.user.get_profile():
      << do something here >>
```

but doing it this way errors out. Is there a best practice for testing for the existence of a user profile module?

Comment: Why not just catch the exception and create one?

Comment: [Uhh...](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: What kind of workflow would you suggest for creating a user profile in that context?

Comment: Catching the exception and either creating the profile, or doing without.

Comment: Right, I get that, but I'm wondering how to create the profile?

Comment: Either create an instance of the profile model and save it or use the `create()` method of the manager, and then assign it to the user and save that.

Comment: Thanks! Is there an elegant way to make sure the UserProfile gets created when a user gets created?

Comment: Catch the `post_save` signal for `User`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm obviously new to Django, so I'm not exactly sure what that means. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make sure your UserProfile is created via [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save). Here's a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910359/creating-a-extended-user-profile).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for others with perfectly valid needs for an answer to the OP's precise question, `hasattr()` does the job.  You can safely use this pattern to check without throwing an exception:

```
if hasattr(user, 'userprofile') and user.userprofile:
    // whatever
```