# User registration - another model

Tags: django

models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    code = models.CharField('Invitation Code', max_length=32)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.first_name
```

forms.py:

```
from app.models import Profile

class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    login = forms.CharField(label='Login', max_length=10, required=True)
    name = forms.CharField(label='First name', max_length=10, required=True)
    password0 = forms.CharField(label='Pass', max_length=32, required=True)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Pass', max_length=32, required=True)
    codeword = forms.CharField(label='Invitation code', max_length=32, required=True)
```

in template I use:

```
<form action="{% url 'registration' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

views.py:

```
def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid() and form.cleaned_data['password0']==form.cleaned_data['password1'] and form.cleaned_data['rules_agree']: 
            try:
                user = User.objects.create_user(form.cleaned_data['login'], password=form.cleaned_data['password0'])
                user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
                user.code = form.cleaned_data['codeword']
                user.save()
            except IntegrityError:
                error = 'Duplicate user'
                return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form': form, 'error': error})

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form': form,})
```

So, the user saves in db, but profile model is empty. I try `user.profile.code`, but result is the same. How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a extended user profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910359/creating-a-extended-user-profile)

Comment: @Hedde I want to do this without signals

Comment: `code` is not an attribute of `user`, so `user.code = form.cleaned_data['codeword']` makes no sense at all, it certainly won't magically create a profile. Either create a `Profile` in your view logic or create your own manager method for automation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add profile creation in your view after you save the user.

```
...
...
user.save()
Profile.objects.create(user=user, code=form.cleaned_data['code'])
```