# Django is not creating the test database correctly

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am using the following database settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
         'NAME': os.path.join(_DB_DIR, 'dev.db'),
         'TEST_NAME': os.path.join(_DB_DIR, 'dev_test.db'),
    }
}
```

However, every time I run `python manage.py test` it breaks. 
The problem seems to be on the test database. For some reason the same tables from the standard db are not being created over there. The command returns `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no such table: tbforms_userprofile` . And indeed, when I open the dev_test.db using sqlite3 it's possible to see the specified table (and any other from the tbforms application) does not exist.

What am I missing? I'm using Django 1.4 with Sqlite

PS: Important to notice that syncdb and migrate run smoothly. The complete traceback is available here: http://pastebin.com/9dVmuVyt

Comment: Have you added tbforms to your project since adding South?  If so, you may need to create initial migrations for the tbforms app.  Or, just set [SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#south-tests-migrate) to `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we've discussed, the issue here is that there's a post save signal for the User model (which is created during syncdb) to create a Profile model (which is created after syncdb, at south's migrate). So, when syncdb (or your tests) creates the tables on a new database and creates a new user, the table for the user profile is not yet created and this error is raised.

**Solutions:**

- Avoid the creation of this profile automatically at User creation (bad smells about it)
- Use Django 1.5 and it's custom user model support
- Disabling south for tests (SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False) and always creating new databases specifying syncdb --all then migrate --fake. (not the best solution, though)

Comment: Got the 3rd option as you know... But definitely I will migrate to Django 1.5 at some point. The user profile signal was created like it was pointed out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910359/creating-a-extended-user-profile