# post_save signal: Creating Extended User Profile, Where to put

Tags: django, django-signals

I want to extend my User by creating a UserProfile object.  I'm following this example:

[Creating a extended user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910359/creating-a-extended-user-profile)

Silly question, but ...errr... where is this file supposed to reside / be called so every time the user is created, this function will fire.  Is the settings.py file a good location?  I'm assuming the user is called in "createsuperuser" and on the register page of my site.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter where it is located, though it is typically found in the same location as `models.py`. To ensure that it is called just do `import signals` after your models are defined in `models.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to have a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model).