# Django - Automatically create object instances when user is created

Tags: django, django-registration

I would like to automatically create some objects instance when a new user is created. I think using signals would be the best strategy but it seems there is no signal attached to user creation.

I am also using django-registration, but I would prefer using signals on user creation rather than on user registration.

What is the best approach for such purpose?

Comment: How about using `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: you mean adding that on user model?

Comment: Django User model? If you want to override User model, you can use that.

Comment: You can attach your own `post_save` signal on the user model. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910359/creating-a-extended-user-profile