# Work with two Users table

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I wonder if is it possible to use the default `django.contrib.auth.models.User` to store admins users, users created with `python manage.py createsuperuser`, but use another table to store registered by form users, also users that will be registered with Social provides (`python-social-auth`). By using another table for users I will need to use the same password hashing also.

Use a 1-to-1 relationship with `auth_users` is not an option.

Thanks.

Comment: What about to intercept the user creation signal and create whatever you want with the related information?

Comment: I'd like to use the built-in function to create users. How can I interceptt that process to save another table and to fill custom fields?

Comment: Seems better explained here: [stackoverflow.com...creating-a-extended-user-profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910359/creating-a-extended-user-profile)

Comment: @ArtemChauzov Thanks, but in that example he's working with a 1-to-1 relationship to the default `auth_user` table, I want to use only another table for users, and keep using `auth_user` for admins.

Comment: Django isn't really designed for this. Why can't you have all users in the `auth_user` table, and use the `is_staff` flag to identify admins?

Comment: @Alasdair That's the way I'd work usually, but this is a requirement. This is working with an existing DB structure.

Comment: @Gocht I faced the same issue. Since the old administrators table only had a few dozens of entries, I manually moved all administrators to the members table, and added a value "Staff" to the "state" field which originally had "Active", "Inactive" and "Pending" states. My custom User model thus have a property `is_staff` that returns `self.state == self.STATE_STAFF`. Maybe this could be accurate for you?

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is how I did this:

From [`python-social-auth` docs](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/settings.html#user-model) is possible define a custom model:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'foo.bar.User'
```

Here I got an error when I tried `'myapp.models.MyUserModel'`, this must be: `'myapp.MyUserModel'`.

This fixed the `python-social-auth` register.

For a common form register I just did a form and create a user in `MyUserModel`:

```
class RegisterAction(FormView):

    form_class = RegisterForm

    def form_valid(self, form):

        MyUserModel.objects.create(
            first_name=form.data.get('f_name'),
            password=form.data.get('pwd'),
            email=form.data.get('email'),
            newsletter=form.data.get('newsletter')
        )

        return super(RegisterAction, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

You can find docs for `FormView` [here](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/).

To fix the autentication methods I created a custom authentication backend:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

from myapp.models import MyUserModel

class MyAuthenticationBackend(object):

    MODEL = MyUserModel

    def authenticate(self, email, password):
        """
            Returns a User (MODEL instance) if email and password match
        """
        if email and password:
            try:
                user = self.MODEL.objects.get(email=email)
                if check_password(password=password, encoded=user.password):
                    return user
                return None
            except self.MODEL.DoesNotExist:
                return None
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        """
            Returns a User based on user_id
        """
        try:
            user = self.MODEL.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            return user
        except self.MODEL.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        except self.MODEL.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            return None
```

You can find authentication backends docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends) and how write your own backend [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend).

Then you need to register your new backend:

```
# Authentication Backends
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'myapp.backends.MyAuthenticationBackend',
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
]
```

You will find `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` settings docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#authentication-backends)

Now I can go to a shell:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
>>> authenticate(email='someuser@somemail.com', password='123')
<MyUserModel: MyUserModel object>
>>>
```

And still can create user with `python manage.py createsuperuser`, which are stored in default `auth_user` table.