# Django Signal User when is registred with facebook

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-signals

I am asking for how to add a Signal in model **User** and know if that user was registred through **Facebook**, I mean, if an new **User** is created in Django with **Facebook** I want to catch this event and save a new Customer model.
I believe that could be something like That:

```
# SIGNALS AND LISTENERS
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import signals
from django.dispatch import dispatcher
form customers.model import Customer

# User
def user_post_save(sender, instance, signal, *args, **kwargs):
    # Creates user profile
    if user # <- SOMETHGING LIKE IF USER IS LOGGED IN WITH FACEBOOK...
        customer = Customer.objects.get_or_create(owner=instance)

dispatcher.connect(user_post_save, signal=signals.post_save, sender=User)
```

In the comment you can see what I need.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Django provides of built-in signals : [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save),[pre_init](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#pre-init)...

use this like:

```
def password_change_signal(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=instance.username)
        if not hasattr(user, 'userprofile'):
            print 'has no profile'
            return
        if not user.password == instance.password:
            print 'setting vals'
            profile = user.get_profile()
            profile.force_password_change = False
            profile.save()
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        pass

signals.pre_save.connect(password_change_signal, sender=User,dispatch_uid='members.models.UserProfile')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910359/creating-a-extended-user-profile), You can use `post_save.connect()` to save customer object whenever a user is created. Please note that I have pasted and edited code in aforementioned post according to your requirements.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from .models import Customer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def create_customer(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs["instance"]
    if kwargs["created"]:
        customer = user.models.Customer()
        customer.setUser(sender)
        customer.save()

post_save.connect(create_customer, sender=User)
```